# Validation one element in form via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, validation

is it possible to validate input generated via devexpress using jquery?
Each time I try validate my element using:

```
$('name').valid()
```

It returns true despite the fact that I wrote this in devexpress control:

```
Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
```

Validation was possible only when i add "required" to element directly in html.

What is more validation before sending form after clicking in devexpress button works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding:

```
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){ var input = s.GetInputElement(); $(input).attr('required', 'true');}";
```